# Flutter: App keeps going back to root route on hot reload when using go router

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I'm using provider and go router for navigation in my project.
App keeps going back to the route on hot reload.

let say I navigate to a page and I do some edit when I save it just redirect me back to the root screen.

the go router package handles the redirect based on the data from the AuthProvider

so for this instance I create the AppRoute instance in the build widget everything works except on hot reload if go back to the root route

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (context, authProvider, child) {
      final appRouter = AppRouter();
      return MaterialApp.router(
        title: 'Awa',
        theme: TAppTheme.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: TAppTheme.darkTheme,
        //routerConfig: appRouter.router,
        routeInformationParser: appRouter.router.routeInformationParser,
        routeInformationProvider: appRouter.router.routeInformationProvider,
        routerDelegate: appRouter.router.routerDelegate,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

so for this instance I create the AppRoute instance outside the build widget everything works except the entire app is stuck on the splash screen, the provider variables are updated but the widget is not rebuilding

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final appRouter = AppRouter();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (context, authProvider, child) {
      
      return MaterialApp.router(
        title: 'Awa',
        theme: TAppTheme.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: TAppTheme.darkTheme,
        //routerConfig: appRouter.router,
        routeInformationParser: appRouter.router.routeInformationParser,
        routeInformationProvider: appRouter.router.routeInformationProvider,
        routerDelegate: appRouter.router.routerDelegate,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Here is app_router.dart

```
class AppRouter {
  GoRouter get router => _goRouter;

  AppRouter();

  late final GoRouter _goRouter = GoRouter(
    //refreshListenable: authProvider,
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        name: RouteNames.patientHomeScreen,
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const PatientHomeScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: RouteNames.splashScreen,
        path: '/splash',
        builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
      ),
       …………
     
    ],
    redirect: (context, state) {
      final auth = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
      //final auth = context.watch<AuthProvider>();
      print(auth.initialized);
      final loginLocation = state.namedLocation(RouteNames.loginScreen);
      final otpLocation = state.namedLocation(RouteNames.otpScreen);
      final splashScreenLocation = state.namedLocation(RouteNames.splashScreen);

      final isAuth = auth.authenticated;
      final isVerified = auth.isVerified;
      final isOnboard = auth.isOnBoarding;
      final isInitialize = auth.initialized;

      final isGoingToLogin = state.matchedLocation == loginLocation;
      final isGoingToInit = state.matchedLocation == splashScreenLocation;
      final isGoingToOnboard = state.matchedLocation == onBoardScreenLocation;
      final isGoingToOtp = state.matchedLocation == otpLocation;

      if (!isInitialize && !isGoingToInit) {
        return splashScreenLocation;
      } else if (isInitialize && !isOnboard && !isGoingToOnboard) {
        return onBoardScreenLocation;
      } else if (isInitialize && isOnboard && !isAuth && !isGoingToLogin) {
        return loginLocation;
      } else if (isInitialize &&
          isOnboard &&
          isAuth &&
          !isVerified &&
          !isGoingToOtp) {
        return otpLocation;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
  );
}
```

and lastly if I comment out the redirect form the AppRouter and create the AppRoute out side the build everything works as it should